# How to consume parameters in azure devops yml pipeline from a template?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I would like to share a set of parameters across multiple pipelines in Azure devops - I've been looking into templates.

Is it possible to do that? The logic I've seen places the steps inside of the template, but I'd like to those reside inside the pipeline that is fed parameters from outside.

For reference, I'd like to move the parameters from [this YML pipeline](https://github.com/AndrewGuard/flyway-pipelines/blob/main/Azure-Devops-Self-Hosted-Windows-Agent/pipeline.yml) to a template so they can be edited in only one place (DRY code).

Comment: Do they **have** to be parameters? Because you can template variables. You cannot template parameters.

Comment: They do, because I want to iterate through them as objects.

Comment: @Rube As Daniel said, template parameters is unable to achieve, no such feature, the common usage I have post in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, no parameter reuse feature for now.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops

Only Variable Reuse like this:

```
variables:
- template: vars.yml
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#variable-reuse

For parameters, always doing like this:

**SetParameter.yml**

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
parameters:
  - name: value1
    default: xxx
  - name: value2
    default: xxx2
steps:
- template: Useparameter.yml
  parameters:
    testparam: ${{parameters.value1}}
- template: Useparameter2.yml
  parameters:
    testparam2: ${{parameters.value2}}
- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

***Useparameter.yml***

```
parameters:
  - name: testparam
    default: 'test'

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
     # Write your PowerShell commands here.
     Write-Host ${{parameters.testparam}}
```

***Useparameter2.yml***

```
parameters:
  - name: testparam2
    default: 'test'

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
     # Write your PowerShell commands here.
     Write-Host ${{parameters.testparam2}}
```